# Is connecting to sql server 2008 r2 express remotely a secure connection?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-access

I am connecting to a Windows 2008 R2 Server with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed.  I am connecting through a remote connection, not on the same LAN.  I am connecting to the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express through VS2010.  This is simply a database connection made remotely.  Is this remote connection secure?  If so, how?  Does SSL have anything to do with it?  When connecting remotely, how are the passwords that are used to log in remotely to the SQL Server secure?

Answer (score 1):

No, the connection is not secure in terms of people being able to sniff the packets, and see the data (or some of it) being returned. You'll need either certificates, IPSEC, VPN, or something similar.

If you are logging into the SQL Server using windows credentials that should be more secure - AD. However, since it's not on the same LAN, it sounds like you might be using a SQL login, which is inherently less secure that a Windows domain account.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server offer privacy (ie. are encrypted) and are tamper proof (ie. signed) if configured so. The protection is done indeed using SSL (actually is TLS, details...). See [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx) and [How to: Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx) for details, including the steps to enforce it.

The question about passwords is a completely different topic. There are two authentication modes supported by SQL Server: Windows and SQL Authentication. If your connection string specifies `Trusted Connection=True`, or `Trusted connection=SSPI` then you use Windows authentication. If you specify a user and a password `User ID=Carpenter;Password=secret` then you use SQL Authentication.

Windows authentication will use NTLM or Kerberos, neither of which require the password to be sent over the connection. But if you use SQL Authentication then the password will be sent over the connection during the handshake. If the connection is not protected by an SSL tunnel, then the password is in clear text and can be snooped by anybody.

As long as you enforce SSL (the articles linked show step-by-step how to do it) you are safe.

Comment: Starting in SQL 2005 the packet with the password is actually encrypted via a self signed cert and sent via SSL so that the password isn't sent via clear text any more.

Comment: @mrdenny: The connection SSL tunnel can be established using a self signed cert, if the client is configured to accept it. But I'm not aware of any 'special' encryption for the password packet if no SSL tunnel is established.

Comment: @Remus, My info is from Rick Byham (BOL team) which he was kind enough to hunt down and provide me for my book.  I'll email you what he sent me (it won't fit in here).

Comment: BOL documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=SQL.90).aspx. I've confirmed that behavior with packet traces myself from when SQL Server 2005 first came out. There's also this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/d4db5036-a968-4bb3-981a-44d1dea27376. Also, technically in SQL Server 7 and 2000 the password is encrypted on the wire, it's just that the algorithm is trivially exploited.

Comment: @mrdenny @Brian: I stand corrected. Indeed, I can see in the traffic that a short lived SSL session is established for the sole purpose of sending over the SQL password, after which the conneciton is reverted to clear. Been like this for 6 years you say? I must be living in a cave...

Comment: That's what happens when you leave the product team for a few years. Now that I've proven Remus wrong I can retire. :)